# Accessing accounts in metamask through web3.js 1.x

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want to retrieve the currently selected account in my metamask plugin through web3.js. And I want to do it dynamically, so when switched to another account, it should be printed to the UI.

I'm importing the library (beta.37) via:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.37/dist/web3.min.js"></script>"`

To make things more complicated: 
1) In Brave `web3.eth.accounts[0]` would log my current address in any other site than my dApp, yet here, it returns "undefined".
2) in Chrome (same build) it would always returns undefined.

To me it is inexplicable how  it can return `undefined`, when other dApps that are built on web3.js 0.x use that exact same code.

Consequently, I can't use the following function, to dynamically print the current address:

```
var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== userAccount) {
        userAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

In web3.js 1.x you must use getAccounts() async method, e.g. as follows:

```
var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
var userAccount =accounts[0]
```

PS: web3.eth.accounts[0] in other Dapps shows your account because they are still using the old web3.js version, very likely the one injected by Metamask